# Sql Array run-time error 13, type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, select, type-mismatch

I need some help. I have the below query returning a run-time error 13, type Mismatch on the **select array** every time I run it with a number of columns select greater than 16. I eliminated columns based on different logic, but the only common thing is that it works if there are less than 16 columns. I know it sounds weird. 
I tried to break the array in different lines, with the same outcome.
What am I doing wrong? Below the code I'm using.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
   With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=CFO_NPR;Data Source=ORDCWPDBSNFD01" _
    , _
    ";Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=EDFLDDIL001;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag w" _
    , "ith column collation when possible=False"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")). _
    QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "Select facility_name, int_no, lwbbs, admit, level, peds, psych, arr, trg, ord, dis, dep, ""arr>phy"", ""arr>dis"", ""arr>dep"",""phy>ord"", ""phy>dis"", ""dis>dep"", hold,  arrh, dish, deph, rept_date, erDisp, ready from ""CFO_NPR"".""dbo"".""efdv_edWait"" WHERE rept_date >= dateadd(day,-32,getdate()) and rept_date <= dateadd(day,-1,getdate())")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .SourceConnectionFile = _
    "S:\ED-EMS\Maurizio Reports\EFD In-Season Performance Report\Daily AH\Daily Stats.odc"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Division_Daily_Stats"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveSheet.Columns("H:L").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YY HH:MM"
```

Comment: This looks odd: `""CFO_NPR"".""dbo"".""efdv_edWait""` - Try changing it to `CFO_NPR.dbo.efdv_edWait` or just `dbo.efdv_edWait`

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you

Comment: `Type Mismatch` typically means you are using a string where it's expecting a number or vice versa, if that helps. Compare your field types to your variable types and make sure they match.